# basic MergeSort exercise

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

**Requirement**: Based on the code provided below, implement the merge sort algorithm to rearrange an array with N elements. While running the algorithm, print array A after each merge of two subarrays.

Input

- The first line is a positive integer N (0 < N < 20)
- The next line contains N integers Who are the elements of the array

Output

- The next lines print out the configuration of array A.

## Example:

Input

10

800 728 703 671 628 625 518 508 392 331

Output

[ 728 800 ] 703 671 628 625 518 508 392 331

[ 703 728 800 ] 671 628 625 518 508 392 331

703 728 800 [ 628 671 ] 625 518 508 392 331

[ 628 671 703 728 800 ] 625 518 508 392 331

628 671 703 728 800 [ 518 625 ] 508 392 331

628 671 703 728 800 [ 508 518 625 ] 392 331

628 671 703 728 800 508 518 625 [ 331 392 ]

628 671 703 728 800 [ 331 392 508 518 625 ]

[ 331 392 508 518 625 628 671 703 728 800 ]

I'm having trouble finding a way to print out the remaining elements of the array after each merge.
this is my code, hope any one can help me:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArray(int arr[], int start, int end) {
    cout << "[ ";
    for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
        cout << arr[i];
        if (i < end) {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << " ] ";
}

void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right) {
    int n1 = mid - left + 1;
    int n2 = right - mid;

    int* L = new int[n1];
    int* R = new int[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
        L[i] = arr[left + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
        R[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = left;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            ++i;
        } else {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            ++j;
        }
        ++k;
    }

    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        ++i;
        ++k;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        ++j;
        ++k;
    }

    // In ra mảng sau mỗi lần trộn hai mảng con
    printArray(arr, left, right);
    cout << endl;

    delete[] L;
    delete[] R;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

        mergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right);

        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    int* arr = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cin >> arr[i];

    mergeSort(arr, 0, N - 1);

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

After running my code, this is the output of example :

[ 728 800 ]

[ 703 728 800 ]

[ 628 671 ]

[ 628 671 703 728 800 ]

[ 518 625 ]

[ 508 518 625 ]

[ 331 392 ]

[ 331 392 508 518 625 ]

[ 331 392 508 518 625 628 671 703 728 800 ]

As you can see, this is not contain the entire array but only print the  elements already be merged, i want it look like the output example.

Comment: What are the symptoms of the trouble you are having? Maybe [edit] and try for [ask].

Comment: What is the current output and expected output?

Comment: It looks like you need to print the entire array (from 0 to N-1), not just the portion you merged (from left to right). This means you need to pass `N` through `mergeSort` and `merge` down to `printArray`. Also please don't post updates in comments, [edit] yout question instead.

Comment: could you add code for me i still don't understand

Comment: @MaiDương -- *i still don't understand* -- Does `printArray` know the actual number of elements in the array?  It doesn't -- all it knows are two values `start` and `end`.  As mentioned, you need to tell `printArray` that there are `N` elements in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem is that `printArray` is not designed to print the entire array.  It only knows to print the elements between `start` and `end`.  It has no idea to print the elements before `start`, and the elements after `end`.

For `printArray` to print all of the elements, you must pass the information to `printArray` that there are `N` elements in total, not just `start` and `end`.  Once that's done, then all `printArray` needs to do is

1. Print the elements before `start`.
2. Print the elements between `start` and `end`.
3. Print the elements after `end`.

The simplest way to do this is add an extra argument to the `merge`, `mergeSort` and `printArray` function that denotes the number of elements in the array:

1. `void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right, int numElements)`
2. `void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right, int numElements)`
3. `void printArray(int arr[], int start, int end, int numElements)`

In `main`, you would call `mergeSort` like this:

`mergeSort(arr, 0, N - 1, N);`

and all the calls to `mergeSort`, `merge` and `printArray` would pass the value of `numElements`, eventually ending up in `printArray`.

Then for `printArray`, the function is very simple:

```
void printArray(int arr[], int start, int end, int numElements) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < start; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << "[ ";
    for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
        cout << arr[i];
        if (i < end) {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << " ] ";

    for (int i = end + 1; i < numElements; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7a36xbYd5)

Comment: A simpler way would be to make `N` a global variable, rather than changing the function interfaces.

Comment: thank everyone for the answer, i fixed the problem correctly.